# missing database (near "where": syntax error)

Tags: java, sqlite

I am trying to update my sqlite3 database but its giving this error.I was able to successfully insert data to same database but I am not able to update it.Please help.

```
[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "where": syntax error)
at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:909)
at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:921)
at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:886)
at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare_utf8(Native Method)
at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare(NativeDB.java:127)
at org.sqlite.core.DB.prepare(DB.java:227)
at org.sqlite.core.CorePreparedStatement.<init>(CorePreparedStatement.java:45)
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.<init>(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:30)
at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4PreparedStatement.<init>
```

my code

```
btnUpdate = new JButton("Update");
    btnUpdate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {
                String query = "update students set ID='"+ id.getText() +"' , username='"+ username.getText() + "', password='"+ pass.getText() +"', firstname='"+ fname.getText() +"','"+ lname.getText() +"' WHERE ID='"+ id.getText() +"'  ";
                PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                pst.execute();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"data updated successfully");

                pst.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    btnUpdate.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    btnUpdate.setBounds(199, 246, 126, 43);
    contentPane.add(btnUpdate);
```

Comment: Important side note: the way you build your query is vunerable to SQL injection. Since you're already using a `PreparedStatement` build it like `... set ID=?, username=?, ...` and then call `pst .setParameter(index, value)`. That way `PreparedStatement` will take care of escaping the value, type conversions etc. _and_ the query will be much easier to read and to spot errors.

Comment: Background: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Print out `query`, copy and try to run that. It should give you some direction.

Comment: Another a little less important side note: learn about the event dispatch thread. Right now you're executing your query directly in the action which, if the query takes a while to execute, could block any further ui updates or events (such as input events) until that query is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here  you added the lastname value without the field:

```
... +"','"+ lname.getText() +"' ...
```

You missed the **lastname** parameter before the value, something like:

```
... +"', lastname='"+ lname.getText() +"' ...
```

which become

```
String query = "update students set ID='"+ id.getText() +"' , username='"+ username.getText() + "', password='"+ pass.getText() +"', firstname='"+ fname.getText() +"', lastname='"+ lname.getText() +"' WHERE ID='"+ id.getText() +"'  ";
```

Comment: I'd add what that portion of the query would look like in both cases to make it clearer, i.e. `..., firstname='bobby','tables' WHERE ID='...` vs `..., firstname='bobby', lastname='tables' WHERE ID='...`.